# How to display error message when a row not found in $wpdb?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, row

I want to display a message if a booking ID is found in the $wpdb and want to display another message if the booking ID not found in any row in the database.

So I am using following code:

```
$booking_ID = $_POST["booking_ID"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bookingTBL WHERE booking_ID LIKE '$booking_ID'";
$result = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if (count($result) > 0){
    echo 'Booking ID <b>'.$booking_ID.'</b>` is found';
    }
else {
    echo 'We could not fint the booking ID <b>'.$booking_ID.'</b><br/>Please refine your booking ID';
}
```

if a row found with the booking ID then the message `Booking ID **GHT65VF** is found` is displayed but when there is no row found with the booking ID then it shows blanks. no any messages.

Why is that?

How can I show not found message too when there is no any row with booking ID entered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all when `$wpdb->get_results($sql)` does not return any thing then it execute 2nd block `die(mysql_error())` which will show a fatal error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_error()

If you enable `WP_DEBUG` mode you will get the error, so this is the reason you are getting blank screen.

Secondly to get the Error log refer to [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/179074/103815).

So your full code should be like this

```
global $wpdb;
$booking_ID = $_POST["booking_ID"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bookingTBL WHERE booking_ID LIKE '$booking_ID'";
$result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
//checking error msg
if ($wpdb->last_error !== '') {
    $wpdb->print_error();
    die('-- code execution discontinued --');
}
if (count($result) > 0) {
    echo 'Booking ID <b>' . $booking_ID . '</b>` is found';
} else {
    echo 'We could not fint the booking ID <b>' . $booking_ID . '</b><br/>Please refine your booking ID';
}
```

Please Note: *You should be using prepare statement and should sanitize input.*

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for explanation. That really helped